# SQL Server : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'." in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Merge into AyubMedicalHospital.dbo.Patient pt 
using AlNoorHospital.dbo.Patient ps ON (pt.patient_id = ps.patient_id)

When Matched Then
    Update 
    Set Name = ps.Name,
        Gender = ps.Gender, 
        Age = ps.Age,
        Addres = ps.Addres,
        admission_Date = ps.admission_Date

When Not Matched Then 
    insert into dbo.Patient(pt.Patient_id , pt.Name , pt.Gender , pt.Age , pt.addres , pt.admission_Date)
    values(ps.Patient_id,ps.Name,ps.Gender,ps.Age,ps.addres,ps.admission_Date);
```

Comment: what is your initial query

Comment: `INSERT INTO dbo.Patient` should just be `INSERT` and don't add the `pt.` prefix in the column list

Comment: now its giving me error that "Incorrect syntax near 'patient_id'"

Answer (score 1):

Since the `MERGE` statement already defines what your **target** table is, your `INSERT` statement must look like this:

```
When Not Matched Then 
    insert (Patient_id, Name, Gender, Age, addres, admission_Date)
    values(ps.Patient_id, ps.Name, ps.Gender, ps.Age, ps.addres, ps.admission_Date);
```

You **must not** have an `INTO tableName` clause after your `INSERT` - just a list of columns you're targeting.

Comment: @Shaourkhan: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.